# React Three Fiber - THREE.BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere(): Computed radius is NaN. The "position" attribute is likely to have NaN values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, webgl, react-three-fiber

I'm creating an website using Reactjs and React Three Fiber for 3d components, I have total 3 3d components and 2 of them are working fine, suddenly one of them stopped working and It's like more that 6 hr. I can't find any answer.

I'm getting this error - "THREE.BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere(): Computed radius is NaN. The "position" attribute is likely to have NaN values."

This is the code -

```
import React, { Suspense, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls, Preload, useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";

import CanvasLoader from "../Loader";

const Computers = ({ isMobile }) => {
  const computer = useGLTF("./desktop_pc/scene.gltf");

  return (
    <mesh>
      <hemisphereLight intensity={0.15} groundColor='black' />
      <spotLight
        position={[-20, 50, 10]}
        angle={0.12}
        penumbra={1}
        intensity={1.5}
        castShadow
        shadow-mapSize={1024}
      />
      <pointLight intensity={1} />
      <primitive
        object={computer.scene}
        scale={isMobile ? 0.7 : 0.75}
        position={isMobile ? [0, -3, -2.2] : [0, -3.25, -1.5]}
        rotation={[-0.01, -0.2, -0.1]}
      />
    </mesh>
  );
};

const ComputersCanvas = () => {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Add a listener for changes to the screen size
    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)");

    // Set the initial value of the `isMobile` state variable
    setIsMobile(mediaQuery.matches);

    // Define a callback function to handle changes to the media query
    const handleMediaQueryChange = (event) => {
      setIsMobile(event.matches);
    };

    // Add the callback function as a listener for changes to the media query
    mediaQuery.addEventListener("change", handleMediaQueryChange);

    // Remove the listener when the component is unmounted
    return () => {
      mediaQuery.removeEventListener("change", handleMediaQueryChange);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Canvas
      frameloop='demand'
      shadows
      dpr={[1, 2]}
      camera={{ position: [20, 3, 5], fov: 25 }}
      gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
        <OrbitControls
          enableZoom={false}
          maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
          minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
        />
        <Computers isMobile={isMobile} />
      </Suspense>

      <Preload all />
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default ComputersCanvas;
```

Now when I comment this component then the code works fine and this component not shown, but when I uncomment it then it appears until I refresh the page and again an white screen appears. Screenshots can help you understand more.

[image: Image for error and screen]

Answer (score 0):

Change Float32Array(5000) to Float32Array(5001), which should solve your issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).